# How to reset to factory defaults a Teac HD-35NAS?

Tags: external-hard-drive, nas

I have a relatively old [Teac HD-35NAS](http://www.trustedreviews.com/networking/review/2005/11/13/Teac-HD-35NAS/p1) but I don't know the password for the web interface so I cannot configure it... I took it from a "garage sale" and the old owner has no idea what's the password.
I was searching for a few hours for a way to reset the password but I couldn't find any info.
Does anyone knows how to do it?
Btw, there is no "reset button" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default username and password is admin, admin, unless someone changed it.

User guide here
http://safemanuals.com/314159.php?k=7dd41b8d41d98c81ddaaa3a8fcc4d513&ID=93487&q=TEAC%20HD-35NAS

Sometimes disconnecting the power cord, then hold the power button in while you connect the power back may do a reset.

Comment: What exactly worked? Default password or the power up trick?

Comment: The power up trick :)